# How to develpo the web based application that can be viewed on the mobile phone in asp.net(vs2008)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

sir
     I am the beginner of the asp.net,for my current project i need to develop a mobile web application using asp.net 3.5 that can be viewed on an Phone and all other browser what to support it, but there is no longer a template in VS2008 to enable mobile development. please give some more idea about that sir,Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a page that is specific to each mobile browser you want to target, or create one that works on the lowest common feature set across all.

Using ASP.NET or any other server based framework should make any difference, it is more how you render it and what functionality you provide to the limited mobile browsers that is key.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about General Mobile development at http://www.mobiforge.com/

For ASP.NET specific technologies look at http://mdbf.codeplex.com/

Details about using MDBF (with ASP.NET MVC - but the basics still apply) cand be found at:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx or the video at http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T20F.

Answer (score 0):

For publishing mobile content from the same URL than web content you can use mobile phone detection software. Try:

http://www.moviladetection.com/