# mobile web application using asp.net(vb2008)

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website

Sir thanks for your replay ,I want how to create a page that is specific to each mobile browser,and how to use the mobile control,sir i want some more idea to learn about that mobile application,and also sample coding sir

Comment: Is this a follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801568/how-to-develpo-the-web-based-application-that-can-be-viewed-on-the-mobile-phone-i/

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman gave a good presenation on this exact topic: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Mobile Controls are no longer supported.

http://mdbf.codeplex.com/ is the nearest equivalent.